# Manage authorization with CanCanCan and Knock auth Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, rails-admin, cancancan

I have a Rails API backend and a ReactJS frontend for which I built an authentication system with the [knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock) and the [bcrypt](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby) gems.

I started to use [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to manage user authorization rules for the admin pages of my app (I use [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) which recommends to use CanCanCan [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCanCan)).

However, it seems cancancan can't access to `current_user`, the code bellow is the model/ability.rb file and seems right:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user && user.is_admin
      can :manage, :all
      can :access, :rails_admin # allow everyone to read everything
    end
  end
end
```

But although I am logged in with an admin user account, the access to the /admin pages is denied.

How can I access `current_user` in `model/ability.rb` ?

Comment: What do you get if you `puts(user.inspect)` at the top of `initialize`?

Comment: Hi @JaredBeck, than you so much for your help. I simply get `nil`.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with authentication, not with cancan. Can you edit this question to be focused on authentication? Please include all the relevant parts of your `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Hi @JaredBeck, You are probably right; I actually changed my auth system to go with Devise and it finally made things much easier.

Comment: Cool, devise is very popular, a safe choice. Please close this question, I don't think it will help any future readers.

Comment: You also can try this gem [rails_jwt_auth](https://github.com/rjurado01/rails_jwt_auth)